# PHP - How to add a specific character at the end of a string?

Tags: php

I am looking for hours how can i add an specific character at the end of a string.

Here is my code:

```
$string = "I have a";
$AddToEnd = "]";
```

I want to make `AddToEnd` to appear after the last character in `$string`.

How it is possible, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is called concatenation.

In PHP you have ms to do that :

```
$concat = $string . $AddToEnd;
```

Comment: Yeah my bad on that indeed, didn't that work years ago?

Comment: Indeed, it was echo. Well, deserve a small down point for that !

Comment: Fun fact: using seperators to echo multiple values is faster than to concatenate them!

Comment: @TimDev - not to mention that it eliminates the memory overhead of the concatenation as well

Comment: @MarkBaker Agree! Just to be off-topic a little bit. thanks a lot for PHPOffice, I love PHPExcel ;)

Comment: @TimDev - Thanks, always good to hear from somebody that likes it

Answer (score 10):

See PHP's [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to see how to concatenate strings:

```
$finalString = $string . $AddToEnd;
// OR
$string .= $AddToEnd
```

You can also use a function like [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$finalString = implode(array($string, $AddToEnd));
```

Comment: I know, I recognized that within seconds and fixed it (in fact you can't even see it in the edit history). You guys were quick! LOL -- well deserved down votes though, I'm still waking up :)

Comment: @KA_lin he keeps changing his answer it was incorrect

Comment: Ahh be the first no matter what I guess

Comment: I've removed my downvote, since the error is fixed. However, I would remove the `implode()` alternative since I don't see a benefit from it. But, yes; it does the job.

Comment: @hek2mgl the only reason I put the alternative is because sometimes SO questions are really basic and they actually want to do something different. In some cases, `implode()` is a better way to concatenate strings. And at that point, if I remove it, I might as well just delete my question. Thanks people for removing the downvotes, that was a total lapse in memory for me...

Comment: It was just IMHO ... Looks good now. I upvoted the post already ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you concatenate them

```
$string = "I have a";
$AddToEnd = "]";
$string = $string . $AddToEnd;

echo $string;
```

output

```
I have a ]
```